# How to make the mouse pointer animate while launching in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, mouse-pointer

My kids tend to double-click application icons multiple times in GNOME if the program has not started yet. In Windows and KDE, application icons temporarily change and animate while the program is launching. Is there a way to achieve this in GNOME for Ubuntu 22.04.

thanks!